# How to tell Pycharm that a certain project must be able to import files from another project?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Say I have a directory and files structure like this; every directory is one project under Pycharm:

```
Project_A/a.py
Project_B/b.py
```

In file b.py I would like to do something like:

```
from a import foo
```

Pycharm flags the above line with an error:

> Unresolved reference "a"

How can I direct Pycharm and Python 3 to find and import ../Project_A/a.py ?

I could do it for Python 3 with

```
sys.path.append("../Project_A/")
```

but Pycharm ignores that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is how, from PyCharm documentation:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/project-dependencies.html